# Get a parameter from one select clause instead of two

Tags: sql, select

I want to get a parameter from a select clause in one time, instead of two selects.

Currently, I'm doing this :

```
SELECT 
    Idx_Pro, 
    Name, 
    Mail,
    IsValidateUser
FROM 
    MyTable 
WHERE 
    [Mail]  = @Mail 
AND 
    [Password] = @password  

If (@@ROWCOUNT > 0)
SET  @Id_output = (SELECT Id_User 
           FROM     MyTable 
               WHERE  [Mail]    = @Mail 
           AND  [Password]  = @password                         
               )
```

I tried this :

```
    DECLARE @Id_output int

SELECT 
    [@Id_output] = Idx_Pro, 
            ...
    FROM  MyTable 
    ...
```

But I can't get it ...

Is it even possible to get only one column in a variable ? (My select returns only one row)

thanks,
TonyFlow

Answer (score 0):

Are you looking to both return the 4 column result and assign to the variable in one operation? If so that isn't possible. You could assign all the column values to variables or parameters then select those to return the result set though.

```
DECLARE @Idx_Pro        INT,
        @Name           VARCHAR(50),
        @IsValidateUser BIT

SELECT @Idx_Pro = Idx_Pro,
       @Name = Name,
       @IsValidateUser = IsValidateUser
FROM   MyTable
WHERE  [Mail] = @Mail
       AND [Password] = @password

/*No intermediate statement can be placed here as it will reset @@ROWCOUNT*/    

SELECT @Idx_Pro        AS Idx_Pro,
       @Name           AS Name,
       @Mail           AS Mail,
       @IsValidateUser AS IsValidateUser
WHERE  @@ROWCOUNT > 0
```

Comment: True, it isn't possible. I wanted only one field instead of all four and searching google, I understood that I can't. Thanks for ur answer !